# Is there anything wrong with postponing Ramadan fasting until a time of the year when days are shorter?

Tags: sunni, ramadan, sawm, hanafi

If you have missed fasts for some reason (i.e. you were not well in the month of Ramadhan), I have heard some people say that they will wait for the shorter days of the year before making up for the fasts.

Isn't that cheating? Will such fasts be accepted? Or do you have to make up fasts on days which were similar in length to the fasts you missed? Or are you supposed to make up for the fasts asap without delay?

I am interested in the Sunni > Hanafi opinion.

Comment: u must do it asap.

Comment: You can make up the fasts immediately after Eid (you can't fast on Eid); and anytime thereafter. Fasts are for the All Mighty, and not for your convenience.

Answer (score 2):

Compensating for the missing fast should not be merely done for making up for the missing fasts, but this (along with all form of Ibadah) should be done for the sake of Allah (SWT). No one should be accused of cheating in this case, as long as one is fasting completely for the sake of Allah (SWT). Season or day length should not matter to someone who does good things for the sake of Allah (SWT).

From Hanafi point of view:

> Hanafis state that if a person is unable to offer any form of atonement, he or she will remain liable for it until he or she comes to possess the capacity to offer it, and this is what the rules of the Shariah require.
>
> [source](http://sunnah.org/ibadaat/fiqhof.htm)

This means that you should fast as soon as possible to remove the liability from you.