# When to make up for non-fasting travel days during Ramadan? Is there a clash with Eid al-Fitr?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, eid

Due to travelling during Ramadan, I didn't fast for two days, but I'm back to fasting now.  I recognize that I'm meant to make up those two days, but when should I do so?  Fasting directly afterwards clashes with [Eid al-Fitr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Fitr), during which fasting is forbidden (I think).

(A similar question was asked here: [Is there anything wrong with postponing Ramadan fasting until a time of the year when days are shorter?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21519/making-up-for-missed-fasts), which also asked about when to catch up on fasting, and the reponse was essentially "as soon as possible".)

Comment: Even if there's a hadith recommending us to take any opportunity given by Allah for example not to fast while traveling some scholars say: One always has a choice if fasting is easier for oneself one may fast even if there's the opportunity, but if not fasting is easier one is free to take the given opportunity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well as soon as possible **does not mean that you fast on EID day** because that is forbidden.

But **after EID day you should make them up as soon as possible.** (Of-course excluding any days on which fasting is forbidden or relaxed like for women during menses or people who are sick or are travelling)

**Reason** is that as muslims we believe their is no guarantee of we being alive even in very next second, so we should have ourselves clear as soon as possible for such obligations.

That's it, nothing complicated.

Answer (score 2):

There are two days in the year you are **prohibited** to fast (no matter what) these are the two 'Id days 'Id al-fitr and 'id al-adha.
Then there are 2-3 days you are **discouraged** (one might even say prohibited, as one really should avoid fasting these days) to fast these are the days of tashreeq the days after ['Id al-adha](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27733/is-it-permissible-to-fast-on-aidiladha/27737?s=1%7C3.5065#27737).

When it comes to make up your fast you can start right after 'Id al-fitr but must complete your missed days before Ramadan of the following year.

Note that as a woman you are not allowed to fast when you have your menses so you may need to plan well when you may make up your missed days. And it's strongly recommended to make up your fast as soon as possible as already quoted in the other answer.

And Allah knows best!